# Using DOS batch, read 2nd line in a pipe delimited file and extract date from 3rd column

Tags: string, file, pipe, dos, extract

I need to extract a date from a text file. File is in pipe delimited format.
It has series of columns which might or might not have value.
I need a date from the 3rd column in second row. 
After that, write that date in a new file.
How to do that?

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in a batch file?

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims=|" %%G IN (%1) DO (echo %%G > %2)
```

Skips the first line and outputs the 3rd token in a pipe delimited file.  File is provided as the first argument (%1) and then it is echo'ed.

Comment: I guess I missed the "write that date in a new file" bit there too.  Just change the echo to something like `echo %%G > %2` and it will write the date out to a file specified as the second argument...  Edited the main post to add the redirection to %2.